# Beautiful Soup | Python | URL Looping

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, beautifulsoup

Hoping this is an easy one. I have looked through most of the valid posts related to my query (and taken snippets from each) to apply to my own code, but for some reason, I'm not having much luck.

Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

- Loop through the first 3 pages on realestate.com - sold prices
- Get the address and sold price
- Put values into a Pandas DataFrame

If I execute the below in chunks (without the URL loop), it works for page 1. What I need is for it to go through the first three pages and return all 20 listings (per page).

```
empty_list = []

for page_number in range(3):
    url_test = "https://www.realestate.com.au/sold/list-{}?activeSort=solddate".format(page_number)
    r = requests.get(url_test)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    results_price = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'property-price'})
    results_info = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'property-card__info'})
    raw_html1 = results_price[page_number]
    clean_price = raw_html1.text
    raw_html2 = results_info[page_number]
    street = raw_html2.find('a').text
    empty_list.append((street, clean_price))

df = pd.DataFrame(empty_list, columns=["Address", "Sold_Price"])
```

ERROR: IndexError: list index out of range

Have I missed something glaringly obvious?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Adrian

Comment: Do `results_price` and `results_info` actually have 3 entries or not? Check that out.

Comment: Hello! both variables return 20 entries (the last 20 properties sold). I have changed range from (3) to (20) to match this, but it still returns the same error. Any ideas as to what I'm missing? You can run this - using Python 3.5 using BeautifulSoup, Requests and Pandas

Comment: `range(3)` translates to `[0, 1, 2]`. Are you sure substituting 0 results in a valid webpage?

Comment: If he tried range from 3 to 20, same error, then 0 is not the problem. Try without for loop with index 3 for example. Do you get the same error?

Comment: Excellent Point. I changed it from range (3) to range (1,3) and it returned a result, but not the result I wanted. the result was one listing from page one and another listing from page 2 so I'm assuming something is getting lost while it's looping through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(3)` does not begin at 1. It begins at 0. If you want it to start at one, `map` the range to increment each number by one.

```
for page_number in list(map(lambda x: x+1, range(3))):
  ...
```

See the documentation on how to use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).

Add an additional `for` loop inside:

```
for p in range(20):
      raw_html1 = results_price[p]
      clean_price = raw_html1.text
      raw_html2 = results_info[p]
      street = raw_html2.find('a').text
      empty_list.append((street, clean_price))
```

So the whole code should look like this:

```
for page_number in list(map(lambda x: x+1, range(3))):
    url_test = "https://www.realestate.com.au/sold/list-{}?
    activeSort=solddate".format(page_number)
    r = requests.get(url_test)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    results_price = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'property-price'})
    results_info = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'property-card__info'})
    for p in range(20):
          raw_html1 = results_price[p]
          clean_price = raw_html1.text
          raw_html2 = results_info[p]
          street = raw_html2.find('a').text
          empty_list.append((street, clean_price))
```

Comment: Similar to above - it returns a single value from page 1, 2 and 3. Ideally, I want the full 20 listings per page - not random ones

Comment: Ah I see. `page_number` only means you're getting the first result from the first page, second result from the second page and third result from the third page. Check your iterations. I'll update my answer in the meantime

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. What is the best way to post the final code so everyone can see this?